# Security Sandbox violation for socket connection using flex

Tags: c#, apache-flex, sandbox

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.XMLSocket;
import flash.system.Security;

public class DotNetSocketExample {

    private var hostName:String = "170.21.8.0";
    private var port:uint =4000;
    private var socket:XMLSocket;


    public function DotNetSocketExample()
    {
        socket = new XMLSocket();
        configureListeners(socket);

       // Security.allowDomain("*");
       // Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost/crossdomain.xml");
        socket.connect(hostName, port);
    }

    public function send(data:Object):void {
        socket.send(data);
    }

    public function disconnect():void {
        socket.close();
    }       

    private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
        dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
    }

    private function closeHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("closeHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
        trace("connectHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function dataHandler(event:DataEvent):void {
        trace("dataHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
        trace("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
    }

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }
}
```

}

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private var sockExample:DotNetSocketExample = new DotNetSocketExample()

        private function send():void
        {
            sockExample.send(send_txt.text);                
        }

        private function disconnect():void
        {
            sockExample.disconnect();
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Panel width="468" height="116" layout="absolute" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" backgroundColor="#EEEEEE" id="DotNetSocketConnectPanel" title="Dotnet Socket Connect Example">
    <mx:Button x="327" y="40" label="Disconnect" width="95" id="disconnect_btn" click="disconnect()"/>
    <mx:Button x="327" y="10" label="Send" width="95" id="send_btn" click="send()"/>
    <mx:TextInput x="21" y="10" width="298" id="send_txt" maxChars="100"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace TcpSock
{
    class TcpSock
    {
        int tcpIndx = 0;
        int tcpByte = 0;
        byte[] tcpRecv = new byte[1024];

        ////////////////////////////////////////
        public Socket tcpSock;
        ////////////////////////////////////////

        public int Recv(ref string tcpRead)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpByte = tcpSock.Available;
                if (tcpByte > tcpRecv.Length - tcpIndx)
                    tcpByte = tcpRecv.Length - tcpIndx;

                tcpByte = tcpSock.Receive(tcpRecv, tcpIndx, tcpByte,
                    SocketFlags.Partial);
                tcpRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString
                    (tcpRecv, tcpIndx, tcpByte);
                tcpIndx += tcpByte;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error
            }
            return tcpRead.Length;
        }

        public int RecvLn(ref string tcpRead)
        {
            tcpRead = Encoding.ASCII.GetString
                (tcpRecv, 0, tcpIndx);
            tcpIndx = 0;
            return tcpRead.Length;
        }

        public int Send(string tcpWrite)
        {
            String POLICY_FILE = String.Empty;
            byte[] write = new byte[1024];
            write = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tcpWrite);


            //if (tcpWrite.StartsWith("<policy-file-request/>"))
            //{

            //    POLICY_FILE = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?> \n" +
            //                     "<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy> \n " +
            //                     "<cross-domain-policy> \n" +
            //                     "<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies=\"all\" /> \n" +
            //                     "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" secure=\"true\" /> \n " +
            //                     "<allow-http-request-headers-from domain=\"*\" headers=\"*\" secure=\"false\" /> \n" +
            //                     "</cross-domain-policy>\n";


            //}
            return tcpSock.Send(write);
        }

        public int SendLn(string tcpWrite)
        {
            return tcpSock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tcpWrite + "\r\n"));
        }
    }


    class Tcp
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///class IPHostEntry : Stores information about the Host and is required 
            ///for IPEndPoint.
            ///class IPEndPoint  : Stores information about the Host IP Address and 
            ///the Port number.
            ///class TcpSock     : Invokes the constructor and creates an instance.
            ///class ArrayList   : Stores a dynamic array of Client TcpSock objects.

            IPHostEntry Iphe = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPEndPoint Ipep = new IPEndPoint(Iphe.AddressList[0], 4000);
            Socket Server = new Socket(Ipep.Address.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///Initialize
            ///Capacity : Maximux number of clients able to connect.
            ///Blocking : Determines if the Server TcpSock will stop code execution 
            ///to receive data from the Client TcpSock.
            ///Bind     : Binds the Server TcpSock to the Host IP Address and the Port Number.
            ///Listen   : Begin listening to the Port; it is now ready to accept connections.

            ArrayList Client = new ArrayList();
            string rln = null;

            Client.Capacity = 256;
            Server.Blocking = false;
            Server.Bind(Ipep);
            Server.Listen(32);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: listening to port {1}", Dns.GetHostName(),
                Ipep.Port);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            ///Main loop
            ///1. Poll the Server TcpSock; if true then accept the new connection.
            ///2. Poll the Client TcpSock; if true then receive data from Clients.

            while (true)
            {
                //Accept
                if (Server.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                {
                    int i = Client.Add(new TcpSock());
                    ((TcpSock)Client[i]).tcpSock = Server.Accept();
                    ((TcpSock)Client[i]).SendLn("Welcome.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Client {0} connected.", i);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < Client.Count; i++)
                {
                    //check for incoming data
                    if (((TcpSock)Client[i]).tcpSock.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                    {
                        //receive incoming data
                        if (((TcpSock)Client[i]).Recv(ref rln) > 0)
                        {
                            //echo incoming data
                            ((TcpSock)Client[i]).Send(rln);

                            //check for new line
                            if (rln == "\r\n")
                            {
                                ///receive line
                                ((TcpSock)Client[i]).RecvLn(ref rln);

                                //send the line to all clients
                                for (int y = 0; y < Client.Count; y++)
                                    if (y != i)
                                        ((TcpSock)Client[y]).Send(i.ToString() + ": " + rln);

                                Console.Write("{0}: {1}", i, rln);
                            }
                        }
                        //recv returned <= 0; close the socket
                        else
                        {
                            ((TcpSock)Client[i]).tcpSock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                            ((TcpSock)Client[i]).tcpSock.Close();
                            Client.RemoveAt(i);
                            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} disconnected.", i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to implement flex web application using Socket connection. But I am getting sand box violation error for remote sites in sample application . It is working fine in local.

Error:

```
Security Sandbox Violation 
Error: Request for resource at xmlsocket://170.21.8.0:4000 by requestor from http://localhost/Sample/DotNetSocketConnect.swf is denied due to lack of policy file permissions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Google crossdomain.xml
You need to put this file in the root of your server.